# Rails: Any gems to automatically generate thumbnails from given link?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, image-processing, thumbnails, web-crawler

I am trying to implement a feature similar to Facebook's: when a user posts a link, facebook crawls the linked website, and grabs the most relevant(big) image. I've read a few solutions here and on Quora, but they are mainly on PHP and don't really provide a detailed solution. One answer I found states the following, but as a beginner in Rails, I'm not entirely sure how this would be done:

1.You can simply make a CURL request

2.Get all the images by HTML parsing

3.Show chosen one by the user as Facebook etc do, or show the first(default) image.

Are there any gems I can use (even if I need to combine them) to achieve this? I am also guessing I need javascript as well to allow the user to choose the most relevant photo, but that's not high priority. I would just like to be able to find a photo from the link, and upload it to our Amazon server. We are currently using Carrierwave to do that.

Answer (score 2):

You can take a look at [Ruby Toolbox](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=crawler) for some crawlers but I don't think there's a one that would fit your needs entirely.

I would probably go with my own specific solution.. So, grab the website with [httparty](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty) or [RestClient](https://github.com/archiloque/rest-client), parse the response and look for images with [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org). The logic of the choosing is up to you.

One thing though, you probably don't want to do this when a user actually posts the link, you should do this in the background so that you don't block the user interface. I wound recommend something like [Sidekiq](http://mperham.github.com/sidekiq) for that. Take a look at this screencast [#366 Sidekiq](http://railscasts.com/episodes/366-sidekiq).

Answer (score 2):

I have just published a Gem that does exactly what you need:

https://github.com/rlarcombe/grabbit

I hope this helps!

Comment: Another one (more recently updated): https://github.com/gottfrois/link_thumbnailer

Answer (score 1):

I would use HTTParty, and Nokogiri to grab the meta data from the page.  Most pages use facebook open graph tags these days, which usually include an image/title/description that you can use to create a good thumbnail.

There's a good SO post on grabbing FB open graph tags here: [How to parse og meta tags using httparty for rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220891/how-to-parse-og-meta-tags-using-httparty-for-rails-3).